# Embedded Jetty 9 HTML form sending data to application

Tags: java, ssl, jetty

I have created a simple login form using a servlet receiving information via HTTP POST trough an SSL connection on an embedded Jetty 9 server. The servlet receives the information as it's supposed to but I've been unable to find out how the servlet should communicate with the application jetty is running in. 
The documentation for using Jetty in embedded mode seems to be very lacking and I havn't had any success doing a general search on the subject either. In short:
How do I get information from an HTML login form hosted on an embedded Jetty 9 server to the application Jetty is running in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the embedded mode examples, see the git repository.

http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/examples/embedded/

For communicating out from the servlet to your application, you have many options, but they all wind up being event driven at the application side.

2 Example Options (there are many ways to accomplish this, this is just two quick examples):

1. Simply call methods in `MyApplication` singleton.

   - Put a reference to the `MyApplication` object into a static `MyServlet.app` field.
   - Call your `app.somethingHappened()` in the servlet when you want to communicate what has happened.
2. Listener metaphor.

   - Create `MyServletListener` with the methods representing the events you want the application to know about
   - Make `MyApplication` implement `MyServletListener`
   - In [`MyServlet.init()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Servlet.html#init%28javax.servlet.ServletConfig%29) grab a reference to MyApplication
   - In the various [`MyServlet.doGet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#doGet%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29) or [`MyServlet.doPost()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#doPost%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29) style handling calls, call the appropriate `MyServletListener` events for the action you want to communicate.

*Note: these are naive examples, and don't deal with threads and threading.
But that's another topic entirely.*

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll edit the question to be specific for the servlet question. Probably more usefull for others that way.